# Moving an ibd file temporarily to free up disk space

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.1

I want to optimize an InnoDB table but I do not have enough disk space. I have enabled `innodb_file_per_table`, so each table has `*.ibd` for each of their partitions. For example:

```
512MB /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
512MB /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
 70GB /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
100GB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_a.ibd    (*)
100GB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_b.ibd    (*)
 12KB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_a.frm
 12KB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_b.frm
  4KB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_a.TRG
  4KB /var/lib/mysql/dbname/table_b.TRG
```

Is it okay to move `table_a.ibd` to another disk, optmize `table_b`, and move `table_a.ibd` back to its original place? I don't want to lose any data, or break anything.

*MySQL server version 5.1.73*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make more sense to me to take a backup, remove the table instead of moving it, perform your optimize and then restore the table you dropped. This would avoid moving tables around unnecessarily and leaving your database in an incoherent state. You would also want to prevent incoming connections from the outside by putting bind-address = 127.0.0.1 in my.cnf and then restarting mysql.

Backup your whole database first with mysqldump

```
mysqldump 
--single-transaction \
--routines \
-u root -p nameofdatabase | gzip -9 > nameofdatabase.gz
```

[--single-transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) is the safest way to backup innodb

[--routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines) backsup stored procedures.

gzip just compresses the backup nicely, you can open it backup with zcat.

1: Backup the table in question

```
mysqldump 
--single-transaction \
-u root -p nameofdatabase nameoftable | gzip -9 > nameoftable.gz
```

2: Make sure the backup you created of the table has your data with zcat

```
zcat nameoftable.gz | less
```

Drop the table

```
mysql> drop table nameoftable;
```

3: Perform your maintenance with optimize

4: Restore the table

```
zcat nameoftable.gz | mysql -u root -p nameofdatabase
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation you contemplate is not safe at all if you do it with MySQL running.

With MySQL stopped, it's not entirely safe, because InnoDB will not be happy when it wakes up to find the tablespace missing.

You would *probably* get away with it if you symlinked to the table at its new location before starting the server up, as long as you didn't try to alter the symlinked table.

You would *almost certainly* get away with it if you moved the entire "dbname" *directory* (with MySQL not running) to another disk and symlinked the *directory* so that it all appeared to be in the correct place.

I realize you don't want to move the whole database schema but that's the safer and officially-supported way to do it:

> You can move databases or tables from the database directory to other locations and replace them with symbolic links to the new locations. You might want to do this, for example, to move a database to a file system with more free space or increase the speed of your system by spreading your tables to different disks.
>
> The recommended way to do this is to symlink entire database directories to a different disk.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/symbolic-links.html

**Supported functionality or not, though, make your backup and verify your backup by restoring it to another MySQL Server before proceeding.**

If you don't have a suitable spare server handy for this task, get a cloud server.  Get a big beefy one with fast ephemeral hard drives and lots of memory, and install exactly the same version of MySQL Server on it.  You'll only need it for a few hours for testing your backup, and the major IAAS cloud providers bill hourly with no commitment or setup fee.  Shut it down when you're done and you'll end up paying very little for it.